# GTA 5 How to login to social club?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So I just got GTA 5 on PC and I wanted to go online and it said to sign in and I don't know how Anybody Help Me I want to go online to play with my friends is it my internet or my GTA files please help me. :(

Comment: If you launch GTA V through the launcher it will ask you to log in or create an account. You are probably launching the game directly with the GTAV.exe. Try launching the game with the launcher

Comment: I will try now thank you                                                                               EDIT did not work  sorry

Comment: @CBJR Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the **Home** button on your keyboard will or should open the social club menu, you should be able to sign in from there.

If that doesn't work, look in the controls menu and find the button to open Social Club.